# Is there any rules or importance of order when using multiple optional patterns in DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, java-time, date-parsing

The below code works fine

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss][yyyy-MM-dd]");
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("1991-01-28", formatter));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("1991-01-28 00:00:00", formatter));
```

But this throws an exception(**the only difference is the order of pattern**)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[yyyy-MM-dd][yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]");
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("1991-01-28", formatter));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("1991-01-28 00:00:00", formatter));
```

**Here is the parseException**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1991-01-28 00:00:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
```

I could not find the reason of this behavior. What is the reason behind this?

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34657355/4290096) that may be similar to mine , but I'm not sure if this is a duplicate.

Comment: The question you link to is similar enough that I would immediately consider yours a duplicate. Since you were unsure, it may be fair to say that it is not an *exact* duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience the rule of thumb is to put the longer format before the shorter one, as in your first snippet. Your observations seem to confirm my rule. Not that I’ve seen it described anywhere, you may want to search, and you may well find.

What happens in the second case is that the first optional pattern matches `1991-01-28`. The remaining string is `00:00:00` (with a leading space). This remainder does not match the second optional pattern, which is then skipped. After that the message you get

> unparsed text found at index 10

very well describes the situation.

Comment: Hmm, but is this the expected behavior? Could not find any documentation related to optional pattern.

Comment: It may not be clearly documented, but all the parsing I have heard of happens from the beginning and working towards the end, so if we assume that this is the case here too, I think it would follow that the optional patterns are tried in order. It’s the behaviour *I*  would expect. Its unlike matching regular expression, which backtracks. Date-time-parsing doesn’t do that.